# JQuery function not working in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

For some reason my JQuery is not working on my bootstrap modal. The form's JQuery function is working fine on the original page, but not on the modal. Can someone please tell me or explain to me why this is occurring. Thanks!

Heres the code:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="changepw" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="changepwlabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="changepwlabel">Change Password</h4>
          </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="changepwdiv">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>



<form action="changepassword.php" method="post">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Current Password</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">New Password</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password_new" id="password_new">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">New Password Again</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password_new_again" id="password_new_again">
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Change" id="change" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="e642d82eed2e2a90529d9debbef45eec">
</form>

<script>
function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#password_new").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#password_new_again").val();

if (password == confirmPassword)
    document.getElementById("change").disabled = false;
else
    document.getElementById("change").disabled = true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#password_new_again").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});



</script> </div>
</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see for any console errors???

Comment: Nope, no console errors

Comment: what is the actual problem you are facing ... your form in not submitting or something else??

Comment: The function is not working @Kartikeya

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#password_new_again").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('keyup','#password_new_again',function(){
    checkPasswordMatch();
  });
});
```

Comment: @user3993537...i think above answer will solve your problem if need more help then plz comment...

Comment: Still not working @Kartikeya I think it has something to do with Bootstrap's modal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem. I was working on the Joomla platform and while inline js worked fine on the form submit, any function calls or event triggers did not. Googling led me to this question.

When I checked the source code of the page I was working on, it seemed that a component was loading jQuery again. So my page now had two instances of jQuery. Removing the instance loaded by the component keeping the main one solved the problem for me. So this could be the culprit in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Joomla JQuery framework you can access it with `jQuery` instead of `$`. So Your code should look like this:

`jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     //code here
});`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  alert("ddd")
var password = $("#password_new").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#password_new_again").val();

if (password == confirmPassword)
    document.getElementById("change").disabled = false;
else
    document.getElementById("change").disabled = true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#changepw").on("keyup","#password_new_again",checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="modal fade in" id="changepw" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="changepwlabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="changepwlabel">Change Password</h4>
          </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="changepwdiv">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>



<form action="changepassword.php" method="post">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Current Password</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">New Password</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password_new" id="password_new">
</div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">New Password Again</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password_new_again" id="password_new_again">
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Change" id="change" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="e642d82eed2e2a90529d9debbef45eec">
</form>
 </div>
</div>
      </div>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: add external scripts in header . and bind the event listener to parent div of modal box and check if the type of event is keyup on dom element targeted in selector call the event handler

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#password_new_again").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#password_new_again").keyup(function(){
         checkPasswordMatch();
    });
});
```